# How to get full path with React Router

Tags: react-router

I'm using React Router 4. I would like to know how to get the full current path in a matched component, not just the base path.

I know that React Router inject a `history` and `location` objects in the props of the rendered component. I've realized that I could either do

```
props.history.createHref(props.location)
```

or build the path manually with

```
props.location.pathname + props.location.search + props.location.hash
```

Are there better ways to do this?